# Is there a way to fire an event every time an ajax call in made in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, express

What I'm trying to do is every time a call to the backend is made, I want a spinner to load up with a dark overlay. I know I can do this by simply running the spinner before the call is made, but I'm working with multiple developers and I want this to happen without any of them having to add extra code. I'm working with AngularJS and I can't seem to find any solutions online so I defer to StackOverflow. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You want $rootScope.$emit('eventName) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular this can be solved with an `interceptor`. See [Angular-loading-bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/) as example.

Comment: Yeah @JacobFinamore, interceptors are the best way to go about this. It'll wait for a request and response, and you can emit an event based on that (the event will be tied to showing/hiding a loader, for example)